# Compilation Error with Boost basic_deadline_timer

Tags: c++, boost, timer, boost-asio

I'm running the simple example program for asynchronous timers given [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io,boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.async_wait(&print);

    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

On compilation, I get the following error:

> /boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void
>   boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer::async_wait(const WaitHandler&) [with WaitHandler = void
>   (*)(); Time = boost::posix_time::ptime; TimeTraits =
>   boost::asio::time_traits; TimerService =
>   boost::asio::deadline_timer_service >]’:
>
> src/TimerTest.cpp:16:21:   required from here
>   boost/1.48.0/common/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:250:43:
>   error: too many arguments to function
>            boost::asio::detail::lvref(handler)( \

I've hunted online for quite some time now but can't find anyone who has faced a similar error. Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function should have signature:

```
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error // Result of operation.
);
```

You can read it [in documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html)

So, just modify your `print` function

```
void print(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
}
```